# Can't import library in Python

Tags: python-3.6

Running python3 xx.py in my specific folder

> shows Import Error

But, I go to my home directory ,and add the new files with same code 
and then it can work well. Why?

I checked both sys.path in these two, the path is same

Comment: If its running fine in one location and not running in another, this is a problem with the paths. Please check the paths of the imports again.

Comment: thx comment first!
I install the "newspaper" packages and then it go /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages.
Does it not just use "from newspaper import Article" ?

Comment: Please be more specific. What's installed where? What is your directory/file structure? What is the actual error message when you do what? What is your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I just  fixed it 
rm -rf  "__pycache__" "__init__.py"  it works!
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. find pycache, init.py

   > > ls -l
2. remove it

   > > rm -rf "pycache" "init.py" it works!

Finally,it is solved